# Is there a clean way to use EF 4.3 Migrations when branching?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm reading up on EF Migrations and starting to play around with it.

I use Git for source control, and every time I start work on a new feature I create a branch.  The reason for this is that if I need to quickly jump to a different feature, or do an important bugfix that needs to be pushed out, I can just change branches and continue working.

Currently I have my app setup so that if I'm not in a production environment (web.config appsetting) it nukes the database and re-sets it up if there have been data model changes (Code-first).  I thought that migrations would be good in that I would not have to completely nuke my data on the slightest model change.

Unfortunately, I am seeing some signs that it isn't as version control friendly as I had hoped.  For instance, if I add a new column to my data model, update the database, then decide to revert my changes, EF is still aware of the model changes because it stores them in the database itself.

It seems like there is no clean way to tell it to downgrade db version when the branch first happened, and then migrate up to where the db is on the branch I'm deciding to work on without a LOT of remembering and manual tracking.

Does anyone have a strategy for how to utilize migrations in a non-trivial development scenario with version control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because each branch will contain migrations that the others clearly cannot know about, there's no way it could know how to transform the database to match (without the use of automatic migrations, which I doubt would work well anyway).

The best strategy for support different branches is for each to target it's own copy of the database, depending on how many branches we're talking about.  That way you're free to jump between them as often as you like and they'll only touch their own database as changes are made/merged in.

Alternatively ensure your core data is part of your migration scripts, and blow the database away like you currently do.

Edit: After merging changes between branches you may need to regen their metadata using the add-migration command.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking.  I wonder if there' an easy way to switch out databases other than manually renaming them

Comment: You could add a cmd to your repo that you can run to gen a new db name in your connection string everytime you branch. Im sure powershell could bang that out easy.